# Tychonoff theorem (2/2)

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, filters

In following I would like to post a proof of Tychonoff theorem using filters of closed sets. I would be grateful if you could find any mistakes in my proof (also if you read and don't find any mistakes). Many thanks in advance:

Let $X_i$ be compact topological spaces for $i\in I$ (some index set). We remember that a space $X$ is compact iff every closed ultrafilter and every closed filter on $X$ have non-empty intersection. Let $\mathcal F$ be a closed filter on $X= \displaystyle\prod_{i \in I}X_i$. Then the goal is to show $\bigcap \mathcal F \neq \varnothing$:

Define $\mathcal F_i = \{Y \subseteq X_i : \pi_i^{-1}Y \in \mathcal F \}$. Then $\mathcal F_i$ are filters of a closed set. Then $\bigcap \mathcal F_i \neq \varnothing$ because each $X_i$ is compact. Also, $C_i := \bigcap \mathcal F_i$ and $\pi_i^{-1}C_i$ are closed.

Moreover, $\pi_i^{-1}C_i \in \mathcal F$, because if $\pi_i^{-1}C_i \notin \mathcal F$, then the filter generated by $\mathcal F$ and  $\pi_i^{-1}C_i$ is a proper filter properly containing $\mathcal F$, which would be contradiction to $\mathcal F$ being an ultrafilter.

Let $x_i  \in \pi_i^{-1}C_i$. Then $x = (x_i)$ is in $C$ for all $C \in \mathcal F$. A closed set $C$ is of the form $\bigcap_{j \in J} \left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_j} \pi_i^{-1} C_i \right )$ where $C_i$ are closed in $X_i$. Also, all of the  $\left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_j} \pi_i^{-1} C_i \right )$ are in $\mathcal F$, because $C \subseteq \left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_j} \pi_i^{-1} C_i \right )$ for all $j \in J$ and $C \in \mathcal F$. It is therefore enough to show that $x \in \left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_j} \pi_i^{-1} C_i \right )$ for all $j$. Since $x$ is in every $\pi_i^{-1}C_i \in \mathcal F$, $x \notin \left ( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n_j} \pi_i^{-1} C_i \right )$ only when no $ \pi_i^{-1} C_i \in \mathcal F$ for $i \in \{1, \dots, n_j\}$. If no $ \pi_i^{-1} C_i \in \mathcal F$, then for all $i \in \{1, \dots, n_j\}$, the filter generated by $\mathcal F$ and $\{ \pi_i^{-1} C_i\}$ is a proper filter properly containing $\mathcal F$, which is a contradiction to $\mathcal F$ being an ultrafiler.

A closed filter is a filter of closed sets.

Comment: Is $\mathcal F$ intended to be a closed ultrafilter or any closed filter?

Comment: $\mathcal F$ is closed ultra filter.

Comment: You can edit your question to clarify. While you're at it, please either prove or link to a proof of your compactness criterion. Asking us to "remember" something comes off as lazy. The only compactness criterion involving filters that I remember off the top of my head is that a space is compact iff every ultrafilter converges. Also, what is a closed filter anyway?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean a closed filter base?

Comment: I'm not lazy. ${}$

Comment: you can show you're not lazy by taking the time to explain that by "filter of closed sets" you (apparently) mean "filter in the lattice of closed sets". Also to explain what "filters of a closed set" might mean.

Comment: I did this already. See the edit in the question.